# run a Ammonite scala script without typing amm

Tags: scala, shell

I try to use Ammonite to write scripts written in Scala
http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Scripting

Example from the website: Args.scala

```
val x = 1
import ammonite.ops._
def main(i: Int, s: String, path: Path = cwd) = {
  println(s"Hello! ${s * i} ${path.relativeTo(cwd)}.")
}
```

to run it:

```
$ amm Args.scala 3 Moo
```

is it possible to write a script that can run by itself, instead of calling `amm Args.scala`, such as?

```
$ Args.scala 3 Moo
```

i tried adding the following to the head of Args.scala:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/amm
```

and making it executable with `chmod +x Args.scala`, but it does not work. it is as if bash (instead of amm) is running the script, and don't understand the first command `val x = 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this header [`#!/usr/bin/env amm`](https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/307).

Comment: it works! i found this info http://linux.die.net/man/1/env , but it is not very well explained. can you please explain it?

Comment: Honestly, I won't do it any better than [those guys](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103467/what-is-env-command-doing) :) But basically it makes available for everything below that line all the commands and definitions in `amm`.